# Unit distance graphs

Tags: graph-theory

It is known that the chromatic number of the Euclidean plane is at most 7. How do we then prove algebraically or in a combinatorial way that the unit distance graphs have chromatic number at most $7$?

Comment: Well, just place the graph on a plane which is already colored in 7 colors.

Comment: This is true. But we have to find a combinatorial or algebraic proof, not the geometric proof that you have referred to.